# Install haroopad correctly from tar.gz

Tags: software-installation, tar

Before you mark this as a duplicate of [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file) hear me out first.

I downloaded the [haroopad-v0.12.0_i386.tar.gz](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/q3gglhci8mx4ysh/haroopad-v0.12.0_i386.tar.gz) file from the [haroopad website](http://pad.haroopress.com/user.html) and extracted the archive expecting to find the normal `.make` or `install.sh` files but they were not there, instead there were two more archives - 'control.tar.gz' and 'data.tar.gz'.

I extracted both of them and below is the file tree. (I ommited the .icons tree structure from data.tar.gz because they are just icons).

**control.tar.gz:**

```
├── control
└── postinst
```

**data.tar.gz:**

```
└── usr
    ├── bin
    │   └── haroopad
    └── share
        ├── applications
        │   ├── Haroopad.desktop
        │   └── mimeapps.list
        ├── doc
        │   ├── changelog
        │   └── copyright
        ├── haroopad
        │   ├── haroopad <-------------
        │   ├── Libraries
        │   ├── nw.pak
        │   └── Resources
        │       └── Themes
        │           ├── editor
        │           │   └── default.css
        │           └── viewer
        │               └── default.css
        └── icons
```

I can get haroopad to run by double clicking the haroopad file (shown above with an arrow) but am sure there must be a better way to 'install' it.

I think I should copy these files somewhere - like the 'Haroopad.desktop' I suppose should go to '~/.local/share/applications', but I'm not so sure.

How do I install this archive correctly in such a way that I can run it from the dash and terminal?

Comment: The site you linked appears to provide `.deb` files for both 32 and 64 bit systems - why don't you download the 32-bit deb instead? You can then install it properly using the usual package management tools.

Comment: @steeldriver I can do that but my question still remains. What about in cases where there are no .deb files?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you unpacked app archive to your `Downloads` directory.

Simply copy content of unpacked `data.tar.gz` to root directory (`/`):

```
cd /
sudo tar -xvf $HOME/Downloads/data.tar.gz
```

Note that it may be hard to uninstall that application. If you want to do so, you must remove every file from the file tree.

Also, it may be required to run postint script from `control.tar.gz`:

```
cd ~
tar -xvf $HOME/Downloads/control.tar.gz
bash $HOME/Downloads/postinst
```